# Does engagement split apply during wait period?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am setting up a journey using engagement splits to determine what leads needs to have their statuses updated in Salesforce. It will not let me add an engagement split without a "Wait By" activity first.

I'd like the lead to be updated immediately when the click occurs, but I am nervous that it's not being updated until after the "Wait By" duration is complete.

**Currently set up the journey like this:**
Send email activity > Wait by duration (2 days) > Engagement Split > Update lead > Send next email activity.

Does anyone know a better way to set this up so that the lead is updated directly after an engagement?

I'd like the update lead action that is determined by the engagement to happen immediately throughout the two day waiting period.

Comment: This is not a use case JB would support, the engagement split doesn't hold the subscriber until they click. Its a lookup to the see if the subscriber has clicked at that time, so if you don't have a wait step they would always go down the did not click path

Answer (score 0):

How you have configured is the standard approach that doesn't require immediate/real time action after an event (in your case a click). It isn't possible to work with real time engagement activity events in Journey Builder. Depending on your scenario, it may be possible to implement an action on the resulting page from the click event to update the lead via an API call or Ampscript (if using CloudPages).